# Python argparse --help description in sentence case

Tags: python, argparse

Extremely nitpicky question, but it annoys me that the default argparse help message is a sentence fragment. For example, for a script that contains

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

The `-h` and `--help` flag message shows:

```sh
$ tmp.py --help
usage: tmp.py [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

However I prefer *complete sentences* in documentation and "sentence case" for headers:

```sh
$ tmp.py --help
Usage: tmp.py [-h]

Optional arguments:
  -h, --help  Show this help message and exit.
```

How can I keep the behavior of `script -h` and `script --help` but change the message?

Answer (score 0):

Welp found the answer 5 seconds later.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.parse_args()
parser.add_argument(
    '-h', '--help', action='help', help='Show this help message and exit.')
```

Comment: I just saw it ^^

Answer (score 0):

Defining your own `action='help'` argument is probably the best answer.  But it is possible to edit the default `help`.

All the defined Actions are collected in the `parser._actions` list.  Yes, it is marked hidden, but people do access it as needed.  Normally the `help` action is the first one created (as default), so it is element `[0]` of that list.

```
In [15]: parser._actions[0].help                                                         
Out[15]: 'show this help message and exit'
In [16]: parser._actions[0].help = "Show this help message and exit."
```

testing:

```
In [17]: parser.print_help()                                                             
usage: ipython3 [-h] {mySubcommand,m} ...

positional arguments:
  {mySubcommand,m}  sub-command help
    mySubcommand (m)
                    Subcommand help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        Show this help message and exit.
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # specific file
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', type=str, default='file',
                        help=Fore.BLUE + '--file access_log -extract-ip' + Style.RESET_ALL)
    # http get file
    parser.add_argument('-hgf', '--http-get-file', type=str, default='http-get-file',
                        help=Fore.BLUE + '--http-get-file URL' + Style.RESET_ALL)
```